# FMA parameter update in LMO org using apex

Tags: managed-package, lma, feature-management, fma

We recently started using FMA app to manage some features in our managed package app. One of the requirement we have right now is on License create/update we need to update one of our FMA parameter (LMO-Subscriber) but in LMO. I don't see any reference to update LMO-Subscriber in LMO using apex (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_lmo_to_subscriber.htm).

Any idea how it can be implemented? I am planning to use Apex trigger to do this on License object.

Also if we implement it what will happen if License record does not yet have that FMA parameter record Can we catch the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In Apex code, you can update data in customer object directly. There are three objects available in LMO: sfFma__FeatureParameterBoolean__c, sfFma__FeatureParameterDate__c, sfFma__FeatureParameterInteger__c

SOQL to see data.
SELECT sfFma__FeatureParameter__r.sfFma__fullname__c, sfFma__License__c, sfFma__Value__c, Id FROM sfFma__FeatureParameterBoolean__c

Comment: yeah.. I figured.. :)